# sql group_concat and where in get inverted results

Tags: sql, where-clause, group-concat

I'm having a hard time with a query.

If I run this (1st bimester only):

```
SELECT subject.name as subject, GROUP_CONCAT(evaluations_mark.note) as mark 
FROM evaluations_mark 
LEFT JOIN subject ON evaluations_mark.subject_id = subject.subject_id
LEFT JOIN user ON evaluations_mark.user_id = user.user_id
WHERE evaluations_mark.number_exam = 1 AND evaluations_mark.user_id = 28265
AND subject.print_visible='1' 
AND subject.number_exam = '4' 
GROUP BY evaluations_mark.subject_id
```

I get this result which is fine:

```
+--------------------+-----+
| Lengua             | SA  |
| Matematica         | SA  |
| Ciencias Sociales  | MSA |
| Ciencias Naturales | MSA |
| Italiano           | MSA |
| Ingles             | SA  |<--RIGHT!
+--------------------+-----+
```

If I run this other query:

```
SELECT subject.name as subject, GROUP_CONCAT(evaluations_mark.note) as mark 
FROM evaluations_mark 
LEFT JOIN subject ON evaluations_mark.subject_id = subject.subject_id
LEFT JOIN user ON evaluations_mark.user_id = user.user_id
WHERE evaluations_mark.number_exam = 2 AND evaluations_mark.user_id = 28265
AND subject.print_visible='1' 
AND subject.number_exam = '4' 
GROUP BY evaluations_mark.subject_id
```

I get this result which is fine too (2nd bimester only):

```
+--------------------+-----+
| Lengua             | SA  |
| Matematica         | SA  |
| Ciencias Sociales  | SA  |
| Ciencias Naturales | MSA |
| Italiano           | MSA |
| Ingles             | MSA |<--RIGHT!
+--------------------+-----+
```

Now, finally comes the problem. If I run this damn query:

```
SELECT subject.name as subject, GROUP_CONCAT(evaluations_mark.note) as mark 
FROM evaluations_mark 
LEFT JOIN subject ON evaluations_mark.subject_id = subject.subject_id
LEFT JOIN user ON evaluations_mark.user_id = user.user_id
WHERE evaluations_mark.number_exam IN (1,2) AND evaluations_mark.user_id = 28265
AND subject.print_visible='1' 
AND subject.number_exam = '4' 
GROUP BY evaluations_mark.subject_id
```

I get 1 of the records inverted (both bimesters):

```
+--------------------+-----+-----+
| Lengua             | SA  | SA  |
| Matematica         | SA  | SA  |
| Ciencias Sociales  | MSA | SA  |
| Ciencias Naturales | MSA | MSA |
| Italiano           | MSA | MSA |
| Ingles             | MSA | SA  |******* <<--WRONG! IT'S INVERTED!
+--------------------+-----+-----+
```

1st column: subjects
2nd column: 1st bimester (first result)
3rd column: 2nd bimester (second result)

why on earth is happening this? thanks in advance!

**EDIT2: replaced the 3 images with text.**

**EDIT3: here are the table structures**

```
TABLE `evaluations_mark` (
  `mark_id` int(13) NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `comments` text NOT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(13) NOT NULL,
  `course_id` int(13) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(13) NOT NULL,
  `evaluation_id` int(13) NOT NULL,
  `number_exam` int(2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

TABLE `subject` (
  `subject_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `course_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `teacher_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `load_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `hours` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `area_id` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `number_exam` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `print_visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

EDIT 4: added needed contents from both tables

evaluations_mark table:

```
mark_id     note    comments    subject_id  course_id   1   user_id     evaluation_id   number_exam     
4363    SA      87  8   28265   0   1   
4892    MSA     84  8   28265   0   2   
1078    SA      85  8   28265   0   1   
3646    MSA     88  8   28265   0   1   
2634    MSA     89  8   28265   0   1   
125 SA      80  8   28265   0   1   
147 MSA     82  8   28265   0   1   
1430    MSA     84  8   28265   0   1   
169 MSA     83  8   28265   0   1   
3753    SA      80  8   28265   0   2   
3510    MSA     85  8   28265   0   2   
191 SA      81  8   28265   0   1   
3775    SA      81  8   28265   0   2   
6858    MSA     86  8   28265   0   1   
3279    MSA     83  8   28265   0   2   
3797    SA      82  8   28265   0   2
```

subject table:

```
subject_id  name    course_id   teacher_id  load_type   hours   area_id     active  number_exam     parent  print_visible   
80  Lengua y Literatura 8   0   1   4   2   0   4   0   1   
81  Matemática  8   0   1   4   2   0   4   0   1   
82  Ciencias Sociales   8   0   1   4   2   0   4   0   1   
83  Ciencias Naturales  8   0   1   4   2   0   4   0   1   
84  Italiano    8   0   2   5   2   0   4   0   1   
85  Inglés  8   0   2   4   2   0   4   0   1   
86  Expresion Plástica  8   0   2   3   2   0   2   0   1   
87  Música  8   0   2   2   2   0   2   0   1   
88  Informática 8   0   2   3   2   0   2   0   1   
89  Educación Física    8   0   2   2   2   0   2   0   1
```

EDIT 4: I MARKED THE RIGHT AND WRONG.

Comment: When you put right side table conditions in the WHERE clause like that, those LEFT JOINS return regular INNER JOIN result. Move the conditions to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: sorry.. didn't follow you.. how's that? can you give me an example?

Comment: First picture 1 and 2 are the same. Second what you mean inverted? Show us what result you expect. Third picture doesn't explain what is the problem because there is another row with same value and you dont call it inverted

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: I tried to export data in ascii in phpmyadmin (the only tool I have) but no luck. If someone knows howto, would be great! already googled it.

Comment: check the link I provide. here is the tool https://senseful.github.io/text-table/

Comment: What is the difference between query 1 and 2? We still need the sample data from original table to see what is happening there

Comment: thanks @JuanCarlosOropeza for sharing the link to convert the tables.

Comment: Again we need the definition and sample data of each table. Is like you show me a cake but dont show me the ingredients. I cant make a cake without ingredients

Comment: added structures

Comment: OK, thanks for the table structure! The only thing missing now is some sample data.

Comment: added some contents

Comment: can you format sample data as table too? so I can put it on a sample demo

Comment: didn't work as expected. Sorry.. but I edited what is right and what is wrong

Comment: if you format the sample data as table I can insert on a table to test the query. Right now said wrong number of columns

Comment: I try prepare a sql demo but the data doesnt match. take a look fix it and let me know. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98da1e/3

Comment: updated the data inside sqlfiddle. You cannot believe it but the result is the expected one. However, in phpmyadmin, the result is different. Why??

Comment: updated sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8b52e/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the `LEFT JOIN` to `user` is superfluous in this query, as no columns from that table are referenced in any way. You can simplify your query to

```
SELECT subject.name as subject, GROUP_CONCAT(evaluations_mark.note) as mark 
FROM evaluations_mark 
LEFT JOIN subject ON evaluations_mark.subject_id = subject.subject_id
WHERE evaluations_mark.number_exam IN (1,2) AND evaluations_mark.user_id = 28265
AND subject.print_visible='1' 
AND subject.number_exam = '4' 
GROUP BY evaluations_mark.subject_id
```

Also, your result should definitely contain **only two columns**: `subject` and `mark`. In hat second column you find several results (letter groups) as a comma separated list.

I created a little demo **http://rextester.com/DXAQIP21690** based on your information (the actual testing data is still missing!) to illustrate my point that the output consists of only two columns. Maybe you can guide us further where your problem is?

**Edit1**
I added the sample data you provided: **http://rextester.com/OVSL70192** Feel free to play around with the demo.

Please tell us: What is your *desired* output? What do you mean by "the result is inverted"? I cannot follow you.

**Edit2**
OK, your comments regarding the "error" clarify your problem a bit further.
In my latest version of the demo **http://rextester.com/XWSO90046** you will now find *two output columns*: `mark1` and `mark2`:

```
SELECT s.name as subject, 
  group_concat(CASE e.number_exam WHEN 1 THEN e.note END)  as mark1,
  group_concat(CASE e.number_exam WHEN 2 THEN e.note END)  as mark2 
FROM evaluations_mark e 
LEFT JOIN subject s ON e.subject_id = s.subject_id
WHERE e.number_exam IN (1,2) AND e.user_id = 28265
  AND s.print_visible='1'    AND s.number_exam = '4' 
GROUP BY e.subject_id
```

Result:

```
subject              mark1   mark2
Lengua y Literatura  SA      SA
Matemática           SA      SA
Ciencias Sociales    MSA     SA
Ciencias Naturales   MSA     MSA
Italiano             MSA     MSA
Inglés               SA      MSA
```

The `group_concat` function in your original query did not have any `order by` clause specified with it, therefore the order of the elements inside was not defined (i. e. arbitrary!). You can improve the situation by using `ORDER BY` in your `GROUP_CONCAT` clause like shown here:

--- incidentally, this is the code that worked for OP (see comments below) ---

## Code, as accepted by OP:

```
SELECT s.name as subject, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(e.note ORDER BY e.number_exam) as mark 
FROM evaluations_mark e
LEFT JOIN subject s ON e.subject_id = s.subject_id
WHERE e.number_exam IN (1,2) AND e.user_id = 28265
AND s.print_visible='1' 
AND s.number_exam = '4' 
GROUP BY e.subject_id
```

This will get you

```
subject              mark
-----------------------------
Lengua y Literatura  SA,SA
Matemática           SA,SA
Ciencias Sociales    MSA,SA
Ciencias Naturales   MSA,MSA
Italiano             MSA,MSA
Inglés               SA,MSA
```

see here: http://rextester.com/UEZ55062 , but please be aware that `mark` is still only *one column*.

**Edit3**
Just tested it in phpmyadmin too:
[image: view of listing in phpmyadmin]

```
select version()
>> 5.1.73-1+deb6u1-log
```

I also tested it on this public sandbox: https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/db_structure.php?server=2&db=Test and it works! Log in with root and empty (=no!) password.

The code as shown above under "Code, as accepted by OP" produced this result again:

[image]

**Edit4**
And a last remark: Strictly speaking you should also be using `MAX(s.name) as subject, ...` in your query as you are only grouping by `e.subject_id`. MySql is fairly (too) tolerant in this respect though.

Comment: it seems to be superfluous but the result is still incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need mark as one column because I need the result in commas for an array in php later, so I need to discard your first option (which I tested in phpmyadmin/mysql and it worked!). As for your second option, tried using the order by as suggested but problem persists in phpmyadmin/mysql. BUT NOT in sqlfiddle nor rextester.com. So.. what should I do? a bug in mariadb/mysql?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. YEs, It works in mysql but NOT in mariadb. There seems to be a bug there. I already reported a bug.

Comment: It **does** work in MariaDB, see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=53a5dc83a6535b7c3cc58112b14ec45f

Comment: oh my god! this one worked like a charm... but I dont understand the difference!! SELECT s.name as subject, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(e.note ORDER BY e.number_exam) as mark 
FROM evaluations_mark e
LEFT JOIN subject s ON e.subject_id = s.subject_id
WHERE e.number_exam IN ($numberSql) AND e.user_id = '$user_id'
AND s.print_visible='1' 
AND s.number_exam = '4' 
GROUP BY e.subject_id";

Comment: The right SQL code has been in my post for quite some time. I marked it as "Code, as accepted by OP" above. So you can simply mark my answer as the right one. There *is* only this answer to your question  anyway ... ;-)